# How can I see and choose what USB standard is being used for a device?

Tags: usb

If I connect a USB device, such as a memory stick, how can I see what USB standard the device supports, and what standard is being used at the moment?

Does the device support USB 2.0? 3.0? What is being used?

How can I attempt to force USB 3.0 over 2.0? Some devices that should support 3.0 appear to run at 2.0 speed.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question, the tool `lsusb` can help you get more information about your USB devices. If you run `lsusb -v`, locate your device, and check the 'bcdUSB' field in the device descriptor which will tell you what version of the USB specification the device conforms to.

In terms of the second part, how to force USB 3 over USB 2, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. USB 3 devices should automatically be backwards compatible and just work over USB 2 but at slower speeds. If you mean if you can force a USB 2 device to become a USB 3 device, to work at higher speeds, then the answer will be no.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I meant rather, how can I ensure a USB 3.0 device actually operates at 3.0? Sometimes I see USB 3.0 devices only working at 2.0 speeds, then after reconnecting it, it might work at 3.0. Is there some auto-negotiation that determines what speed will mostly likely work? If it is possible to influence or even override this, then that would be awesome.